# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TabletoNumPyArray'

Tags: arcpy, table, numpy, array

I am trying to create a Python array using data from an ArcGIS attribute table. Here's the code I've written so far:

```
import arcpy
import numpy
input = "c:/data/from/arcgis"
arr = arcpy.da.TabletoNumPyArray(input,('OBJECTID','SoilEvap5'))
a = arr["OBJECTID"]
b = arr["SoilEvap5"]
np.columnstack((a,b))
print arr
```

When I try running this in the ArcGIS Python window, it returns:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TabletoNumPyArray'
```

Why is this error showing up and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is it you're trying to do here? I can't see any arcpy commands (except import arcpy). What line gives you there error?

Comment: This is a very common error message: http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=attributeerror+module+object+is%3Aquestion

Comment: A good editor will help you avoid this sort of problem. I use PyWin which has some basic InteliSense (you type in arcpy.da. and all the methods available appear)... saves typing and avoids mistyping/incorrect case. Other editors no doubt can do this and IMO it's worth finding a good one.

Comment: I am still happy to just work with IDLE as my Python editor because it also has code completion ("IntelliSense") - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16467896/820534 - but to see that you need to put `import arcpy` and run your code once first.  Also, to force it to auto complete using `Ctrl-spacebar` is a trick worth knowing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct name for this function is [TableToNumPyArray (arcpy.da)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000018000000) i.e. there should be a capital "T" on "to".

Correct capitalization is very important to the Python programming language.

Comment: should the field names be a tuple ('OBJECTID','SoilEvap5') or list ['OBJECTID','SoilEvap5'] or doesn't that matter in this case? Where tools say [field_names,...] I have interpreted that as a list but it wouldn't surprise me if a tuple could be substituted.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I think lists and tuples are interchangeable within at least some (perhaps all) ArcPy functions but I've not tested to say with 100% confidence.